# What does this verilog assign function do?

Tags: verilog

If sig_in = 0000, 0001, 0010, ... ,1111

```
sig_out = {sig_in[3], sig_in[3], sig_in[3: 2]};
```

If I'm reading this right, sig_out[3] will be sig_in[3], sig_out[2] will also be sig_in[3], and I'm not sure what sig_in[3: 2] does. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the right hand side of the assign you have a `concatination` operator `{...}`;
It concatenates bits from its arguments into a single bit stream.

so, if `sign_in[3:0]` is 0101, the result in your example will be:

```
sign_in[3:0] = 4'b0101
        bit 3 ----^
        bit 0 -------^

{
   1'b0, // sign_in[3]
   1'b0, // sigh_in[3]
   2'b01 // sign_in[3:2] -- extracts 2 bits - bit 3 (0) an d bit 2 (1)
}
```

so, sign_out[3:0] will look like the following

```
==>          4'b0001;
sign_in[3]    --^
sign_in[3]    ---^
sign_in[3:2]  ----^^
```